# how to open a solution by msbuild on linux

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, roslyn

I use MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync to open a solution on linux,code is as follows:

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
        Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync("LoadTest/LoadTest.sln").Result;
        foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(project.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

but solution.Projects is always 0,on Windows is 1,windows installed msbuild,do I need to install msbuild on linux?

Comment: Which MSBuild assembly does you use as reference in your project? Also pay attention to the path of the solution as on Linux the separator is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSBuildWorkspace is not supported on Linux; we haven't moved over to using the portable MSBuild yet.

Comment: Are there other ways can load solutions on Linux？or how to create a solution by existing methods

Comment: Your only options are (a) update MSBuildWorkspace to support it, or (b) read through the XML yourself and then construct it manually using AdHocWorkspace or the like.